# Who were the Guardians of Olympus?

Tags: greek, olympians

I am aware of Hercules and his two sons, as well as of the Horae who guard the doors of Olympus, but were there any other deities instructed with guarding the home of the gods?

Comment: As far as i know, no
when Typhon challenged Zeus for control some gods stood with him (Nike and Athena). but this was just this once.